# what is the Regular Expression to print lines that dont have the word you specify?

Tags: regex

i have this output:

```
---------- snippet start ----------
JUnit version 4.11
I.E
Time: 0.015
There was 1 failure:
1) testPerson(PersonTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<John[1]> but was:<John[]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at PersonTest.testPerson(PersonTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)

---------- snippet end----------
```

and i want to retrieve only lines that did not have the word "at" at the beginning of each line,but not including a line (with an "at") that contains the word "PersonTest.java"
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not use a regex that expects `at` to be present at the beginning of the line, and retrieve the line if the regex FAILS?

Comment: you could also use `grep` if you don't nessecerily have to do in programatically, for example: `grep -v "at "`

Comment: like use it in a loop?,i cant do that AFAIK,i can only use regex and cannot use programming language., its the output of my IDE after compilation, and i want to minimise the noise it gives.thanks anyway

Comment: @0x726364 something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/rU3fC3) ?

Comment: i cannot also use commandline utilities for formatting the output, only regular expression is provided by the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

If the IDE's regex engine supports it, the canonical method is to use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
(?!^\s*at\b)
```

(I put a word boundary at the end there in case a line starts with, say, "attached".)

But if the IDE *doesn't* support lookaround assertions, then you'd have to do something similar to what @HamZa suggested. @HamZa's solution is a bit off though, because, for example, it would also filter out lines that start with "as". Here's the correct one:

```
^\s*([^a\s]|a[^t])
```

In other words, after ignoring leading spaces, if your first character is *not* an `a`, then you're good to go—else, you just have to make sure the second character isn't a `t`.

Now, that doesn't take into account the "attached" case. Add this:

```
^\s*([^a\s]|a[^t]|at\w)
```

---

**tl;dr** Here's a regex that should work no matter what:

```
^[ \t]*([^a\s]|a[^t]|at[a-zA-Z0-9_])
```

Comment: Nice **+1** for the extensive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the group captures and can't use lookaheads, you can use this regex:

```
^((\s{4}|\t)*([^a]t|a[^t]|at[^\s]+)|[^\s]+).*
```

You can see it in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/zY0yG3).

The problem is that it's difficult to match `at` like that because the `\s*` will immediately readjust to allow an explicit non `at` character. For instance:

```
at
```

won't match with `\s*[^a][^t]` but will match against:

```
 at
123
```

1 is the first `[^a]` match; 2 is the `[^t]` match. and the `\s*` simply reduced its maximum matches to (maximum-1) matches.

So, that's why you'll find `\s{4}` in my regex to prevent this backtrack of the operator `*`.

Now, I used `[^a]t|a[^t]|at[^\s]+` to prevent matches to `at`, allow everything else and allow some specific matches:

```
a t
attention
```

should match since there's no literal `at`.

Comment: +1. You are absolutely right; I did not test my regex to see this fault. I hope you don't mind me editing my question to incorporate your fixes; but I'm glad to take down my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, in other words, you want to filter out all stack trace lines, except for those that are about the test class itself, right?!

You need a regular expression engine that supports *negative lookahead*, e.g. GNU `grep` with support for `-P` / `--perl-regexp`:

```
grep -v -P '^ *at (?!.*PersonTest)' output
```

This filters out (`-v`) all lines that start with `at`, **not** followed by `PersonTest` in the line.

Comment: thanks, yes that's the output i want to achieve,ive tried gnuwin32 grep but the parameter seems not working on my system, i have windows xp,maybe the 'negative lookahead' is not supported or i dont know. and another how do you pipe something into grep in windows? i think it expects files as input. Thanks a lot.

Comment: With gnuwin32, you have to use `pcregrep` (and leave off the `-P`, and use double quotes), or use `grep` from _Cygwin_.

Comment: For piping, just `type filename | grep -v ...`; leave off the `output`.